# Write execlp result to a file using > instead of open function

Tags: c

I would like to know if it's possible in c to run the following command `ls -la -R / | grep "^l" > somefile.txt` and write de output using the `>`  instead of using the function `int fd = open("output_file", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0666);`.

I have to send this command as an argument to a c program. Something like the following example but adding the processes for the `>` to the required file.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
     int f1[2];
     char buff;

     if(pipe(f1) != -1)
          printf("Pipe1 allright! \n");

     int pid = fork();
     if(pid==0)
     {
          close(1);
          dup(f1[1]);

          close(f1[0]);
          close(f1[1]);

          close(0);
          execlp("ls", "ls", "-la", "-R", "/", NULL);  
     }
     printf("ls-pid = %d\n", pid);

     int f2[2];
     if(pipe(f2) != -1)
          printf("Pipe2 allright \n");

     pid = fork();
     if(pid==0)
     {  
          close(0);
          dup(f1[0]);

          close(f1[0]);
          close(f1[1]);

          close(1);
          dup(f2[1]);

          close(f2[0]);
          close(f2[1]);

          execlp("grep", "grep", "^l", NULL);
     }

     printf("grep-pid = %d\n", pid);

     close(f1[0]);
     close(f1[1]);


}
```

Comment: No. `>` redirection is a shell feature, not an OS feature. Shells translate redirections into `open`s and/or `dup`s.

Comment: You may need to word your question a bit better. Do you really mean no `open` calls anywhere or just that the child processes don't do the open (since they are exec'ed)? The latter is possible - the parent process does the `open` and sets up the redirections before `fork/exec`.

Comment: Check out `dup2` - I guess you need that instead of `dup`

Comment: You can usually use the shell redirection features when calling `system()`   instead of the `exec*()` family

Comment: @Ctx: `system` is a really, **really** bad idea. It's thread-unsafe, manipulates signal state in an unsafe way, and suspends the caller until the child process exits. If you want a standard function that uses shell by default, `popen` is a much better choice, but you can just `execlp` `/bin/sh` with the `-c` option and a string containing your shell command, too.

Comment: @R.. You don't say! `system()` indeed has several drawbacks, but primarily not the ones you mention here

Comment: @Ctx: The other drawbacks are all fundamental to invoking commands via a shell, but can be handled as long as you know how to do it. The ones I mentioned have no way to deal with; they just make the function entirely unusable except in the rare case where you don't care about them.

Comment: @R.. Except that most claims are simply not true.

Comment: @Ctx: Your vague complaints ("most...not true"?) about my comment are not helpful. If you claim some specific point is untrue, state so clearly.

Answer (score 0):

This is not particularly a good idea, but easy to do:

```
execlp("sh", "sh", "-c", "ls -la -R / | grep \"^l\" > somefile.txt", (char *)0);
```